# Rounding the layer on a Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, rubymotion

Came across this article on how rounded layouts generally look better: http://blog.edwardmarks.com/post/9859783254/improve-usability-with-a-black-status-bar-and-rounded

Sounds great, but there's no link to the source code to actually do it!  I'm writing my apps in RubyMotion.

I've had no trouble setting the UIStatusBar

```
 UIApplication.sharedApplication.setStatusBarStyle(UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque)
```

But I can't seem to get the rounded edges I wanted.  I tried with the following in my AppDelegate

```
 @window.layer.cornerRadius = 5
 @window.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

But to no avail.  And when I do it on the view, it doesn't round the navigation title.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try: 
@window = UIWindow.alloc.initWithFrame(UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds, cornerRadius: 5, masksToBounds: true)